# Operator font with newtx

Tags: math-operators, newtxmath

I am using `\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}`. But, `\operatorname{}` seems to use another font.

How to set up accordingly?

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

Comment: @egreg, ohhh I never imagined that the order could be a solution. Simpler than this, impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct order is the reverse, first `newtxtext` and then `newtxmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

notations: $Y=N-\operatorname{int}(U)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In `newtxmath.sty` we find

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\tx@enc}{\rmdefaultB}{m}{n}
```

and `\rmdefaultB` is `\rmdefault`, which still is Computer Modern if `newtxtext` has not yet been loaded,

Comment: Do you mean "if `newtxtext` has not yet been loaded"?

Comment: @user94293, I think so.

Comment: @user94293 Yes, probably I inverted Sigur’s inversion and the inverted again… `:-)`